# find sed: вырезать необходимое

Tags: linux, регулярные-выражения, sed

Есть куча директорий вида `/var/2015/12/21/`, в которых находятся куча файлов типа `123.jpg`, `423423.jpg`, `2183.txt`, `9493.xls` и т.п.

Необходимо для каждого файла создать директорию с его именем без расширения и переместить туда файл, по сути создать ещё одну промежуточную дирикторию, т.е. чтобы получилось так: `/var/2015/12/21/2183/2183.txt` и т.п.

Полагаю, надо просто использовать `find /var/2015/ -type f -regex ".*\.\(jpg\|jpeg\|gif\|png\|JPG\|JPEG\|GIF\|PNG\)"`. Далее в цикле для каждого соответствия с помощью sed обрезать регуляркой 2 части - путь и имя файла без расширения. Затем создать новую директорию и переместить туда файл - вся эта инфа уже будет в наших переменных.

Собственно, не получается написать условие для sed. Помогите, пожалуйста?

Типа как-то так:

```
find /var/2015/ -type f -regex ".*\.\(jpg\|jpeg\|gif\|png\|pdf\|xls\|JPG\|JPEG\|GIF\|PNG\|PDF\|XLS\)" -exec sed 's#^(.+)\/([0-9]+)\.#' {} \;
```

Comment: `sed 's/\.[^.]*$//'` отрежет  последнюю точку и все что после в имени

Comment: @Mike , хмм, в итоге у нас будет абсолютный путь для создания новой директории и абсолютный путь до каждого файла из find чтоб можно было переместить, - это гениально! Спасибо!

Comment: @Mike оформьте Ваш ответ в поле ответа, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю отрезать в пути только расширение: `sed 's/\.[^.]*$//'`